# Rule of thumb on number of zero entries for invertibility of a $4\times 4 $ matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

I have to determine whether a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$ is invertible. Suppose that there are no zero columns or zero rows. Is there any rule of thumb saying how many zero entries can be at most in $A$, or how many zero entries per column can be at most in $A$, or similar, in order to have $A$ invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, a diagonal matrix with nonzero entries along the main diagonal is always invertible, so to answer the original question there is no rule of thumb.  Furthermore, a matrix that is all nonzero may be non-invertible.  You would need to look at the rank of the matrix (or many, many other things, like the determinant)